# Java Connect four error

Tags: java, graphics, jframe, jpanel

I have made a graphics version of connect four but when I run the program it gives many error, can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Right now this code is not reading anything and I don't know why.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class four extends JPanel implements ActionListener,KeyListener {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;  
static int x=0, y=0;     
static int cx=0, cy=0;     
static JFrame f;  
static char [][]a = new char[7][7]; 
static int ccolumn=0;
static int bottom=6;
int p;
boolean Player1=false;    
boolean Player2=false;  
boolean Draw=false;
boolean Gamefinished=false;

public void init (){
    this.addKeyListener(this);  
    setFocusable(true);  
    for(int c = 0;c<7;c++){  //Initialize for connect four to "0"
        for(int d = 0;d<7;d++){ 
            a[c][d] = '0';   
        } 
    }  
 p = 1;  //switch the chips
 bottom = 6; // "bottom" is the empty slot above an chip
}

public void paintComponent (Graphics g){    
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawRect(x,100,700,100);
    g.drawRect(x,200,700,100);
    g.drawRect(x,300,700,100);
    g.drawRect(x,400,700,100);
    g.drawRect(x,500,700,100);
    g.drawRect(x,600,700,100);
    g.drawRect(x,700,700,100);
    g.drawRect(100,100,100,700);
    g.drawRect(200,100,0,700);
    g.drawRect(300,100,0,700);
    g.drawRect(400,100,0,700);
    g.drawRect(500,100,0,700);
    g.drawRect(600,100,0,700);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawString("1",50,50);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawString("2",150,50);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawString("3",250,50);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawString("4",350,50);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawString("5",450,50);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawString("6",550,50);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawString("7",650,50);
    if (Player1==true) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(cx,cy,50,50);    
    }
    if (Player2==true) {
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillOval(cx,cy,50,50);    

    }
    if (Gamefinished==true){
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(1,1,1000,2000);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        if (Player1)
            g.drawString("red player win!",190,300);
        if (Player2)
            g.drawString("yellow player win!",190,300);
        if (Draw==true)
            g.drawString("Draw!",190,300);
    }


}   

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


    if(Player1==true){  //p is switch the chips
        bottom=6;
        for (int b=0 ; b<7; b++){    //calculate bottom for red
            if (a[b][ccolumn]!='0'){
                bottom=b-1;
    //          if(bottom<0)  {
    //              Gamefinished = true;
    //              Draw = true;
    //              Player1 = false;
    //              Player2 = false;
    //          }

        //      break;
            }
        }
        a[bottom][ccolumn] = 'R';  
    }  
    if (Player2==true) {  
        //  System.out.println("Drop a yellow disk at column(0-7): ");  
        //    ecol = input.nextInt();  

        bottom=6;
        for (int b=0 ; b<7; b++){  //calculate bottom for yellow
            if (a[b][ccolumn]!='0'){
                bottom=b-1;
//              if(bottom<0)  {
//                  Gamefinished = true;
//                  Draw = true;
//                  Player1 = false;
//                  Player2 = false;
//              }
        }
        }
        a[bottom][ccolumn] = 'Y';  
    }
    cy=bottom*100+50;
    cx=ccolumn*100+150;


    //if (isfour()==true) {
//      Gamefiniched = true;
    //  Draw = false;
//  }
    f.repaint();

}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    int c = e.getKeyCode();
    if (c == KeyEvent.VK_1){
        ccolumn=0;
        p++;
    }
    if (c == KeyEvent.VK_2){
        ccolumn=1;
        p++;
    }
    if (c == KeyEvent.VK_3){
        ccolumn=2;
        p++;
    }
    if (c == KeyEvent.VK_4){
        ccolumn=3;
        p++;
    }
    if (c == KeyEvent.VK_5){
        ccolumn=4;
        p++;
    }
    if (c == KeyEvent.VK_6){
        ccolumn=5;
        p++;
    }
    if (c == KeyEvent.VK_7){
        ccolumn=6;
        p++;
    }   

    if(p%2==0){  //p is switch the chips
        Player1 = true;
        Player2 = false;
    }
    else {
        Player2 = true;
        Player1 = false;
    }





}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

public static void main(String[] args){

    four tt = new four();
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    tt.init();  
    f.setTitle("hi");
    f.setSize(800,700);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(tt);
    Timer t = new Timer(100,tt);
    t.start();
}
public static boolean isfour(){  
    int c = 0;
    int d=0; 
    int k, u;
    //System.out.println("row"+row+"  column"+column);
    k=bottom;
    u=ccolumn;
    //Check for right diagonal (4 elements)
    if((k<=7-4) && (u<=7-4)) {// Check if it is out of bound
        if ((a[k][u]==a[k+1][u+1]) && (a[k][u]==a[k+2][u+2]) && (a[k][u]==a[k+3][u+3]) &&(a[k][u]!='0'))
            return true;
    }
    //Check for left diagonal (4 elements)
    if ((k<=7-4)&&(u>7-4)) { 
        if ((a[k][u]==a[k+1][u-1]) && (a[k][u]==a[k+2][u-2]) && (a[k][u]==a[k+3][u-3]) &&(a[k][u]!='0'))
            return true;
    }
    //Check for vertical (4 elements)
    if (k<=7-4) {
        if ((a[k][u]==a[k+1][u]) && (a[k][u]==a[k+2][u]) && (a[k][u]==a[k+3][u]) &&(a[k][u]!='0'))
            return true;   
    }
    //Check for horizontal
    for (c=0;c<6; c++){
        if ((a[k][c]==a[k][c+1])  &&(a[k][c]!='0')) {
            d++;
            if (d==3) return true;
        }
        else d=0;
    }
    return false;  // no 4 connections
}
}
```

Comment: *"can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?"* Over use of `static` for starters

Comment: *"I run the program it gives many error"* - Like what?

Comment: can you post up your stack trace?